# Invoke controller action from a web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

I have an ASP.NET MVC application presenting some data and I want it to

- open a new tab, or
- redirect to a new view

when a web service gives me a signal. This WS is supposed to handle some external data and requests and when some specific action is called, I want it to be able to give my web application some kind of signal.

I was thinking about using `Html.Action` to an asynch controller but then I don't know how to provide the signal from the WS to the controller (or all instances of them).

Hopefully, it is understandable. Do you have an idea what needs to be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't open a new tab programmatically. And how is your WS implemented? Are you using WCF ?

Comment: No WCF, just `System.Web.Sevices`.

Comment: correct me If I am wrong, you want to do is >  a user initiates a WS from her browser, the WS processes the request and then invokes your controller, the controller then can either open a new tab or redirect. ? I don't think you can redirect a request from the WS to the controller. It could be done if WS returns the response to the user and their you again a send a request to the controller using Javascript.

Comment: No, a user is browsing a web application. Then on some other channel data is processed (a call comes in and is registered to DB) using a web service. This WS should also signal the web application that would in response change the current view presented to specific user to some other view informing the user that the action has occured (call is incoming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically your problem comes down to the fact that server state is changed (through WS) and we want to make something happen at the client side where the your web app is being viewed.

Frankly it's not straightforward. Internet works on the Client -> Server architecture. User sends a request to the server, server responds. What you are trying to do is reverse of it. You want to send a request from server to user. HTTP protocol doesn't work like that.

Right now, to do something similar following two strategies are used:

1. **Websockets** : try searching them on google. You create a socket between the client and server and once server gets updated by the WS, it sends a request to the client through the socket. You can ask it to navigate to a different view or open a new window. The downside with it is that its not supported by the majority of the browsers. Might take a year or so to be. Not really recommend now.
2. **Polling** : You can make Ajax requests from your browser to server in certain intervals (you know like every 5 seconds) and see if the server state has changed or now. If yes, then do your stuff. That's the most common technique. Twitter.com uses it. There is also another version of it called Comet or Long Polling but I won't confuse you with that.

The important thing to note here is that whatever you want to do (open tab, change view etc) you have to do it through Javascript at the client side.

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I already have the polling approach but it seemed inefficient to me. I knew there is some other way but didn't know how to look for it.